# Vertx timing out for DynamoDB insert calls

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, vert.x, vertx-verticle, vertx-eventbus

I am using DynamoDB with Vertx and one of my verticles is getting timed out with error

**Timed out after waiting 30000(ms) for a reply. address**

```
eventBus.send("test", testObject, x -> {
  if (x.succeeded()) {
        log.info("done successfully")
  } else {
        error(“error while completing”)
  }
}
);
public CompletableFuture<Void> process(Object testObject) {
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> dynamoMapper.save(testObject))
            .thenAcceptAsync(result -> {
        log.info("done successfully")
            }).exceptionally(throwable -> {
                throw new CompletionException(throwable);
            });
}

final void listen(String address) {
    eventBus.consumer("test", x -> process(x).whenCompleteAsync((result, t) -> {
        if (t == null) {
            x.reply(OK);
        } else {
            x.fail(0, errorMessage);
        }
    }));
}
```

But when I run that DynamoDB save query in async I am not having this issue. Can somebody suggest best practices to use DynamoDB with vert.x?

Comment: Can you share the code of how you query (probably send an event on the event-bus) and how you process (probably a consumer)?

It might be that there is an exception in your consumer, which vert.x "swallow" and you get a timeout in the caller - in this case you need to wrap it with try-catch and fail the request on exception.

Comment: Have updated with the code. Can you please check. I am handling for the exception as well. Issue is in case of time out verticle throws the message which doesnt comes in the exceptionally block.

Answer (score 1):

In vert.x, by default, you can't pass pojo's via the eventbus (https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_types_of_messages)

Also, you do not need to use futures as vertx provide most of your needs.

I would use the aws async client, but you can not use the mapper with it at the moment. If you still want to use the mapper, it should be something like the following:

```java
vertx.eventBus().<String>consumer("dynamodb-example", message -> {
  try {
    CatalogItem catalogItem = Json.decodeValue(message.body(), CatalogItem.class);
    dynamoDbMapper.save(catalogItem);
    message.reply(Json.encode(catalogItem));
  } catch (Exception e) {
    message.fail(500, e.getMessage());
  }
});
```

As their SDK is blocking, you can use executeBlocking to avoid blocking the event-bus:

```java
vertx.eventBus().<String>consumer("dynamodb-example", message -> {
  vertx.<CatalogItem>executeBlocking(promise -> {
    CatalogItem catalogItem = Json.decodeValue(message.body(), CatalogItem.class);
    dynamoDbMapper.save(catalogItem);
    promise.complete(catalogItem);
  }, asyncResult -> {
    if (asyncResult.succeeded()) {
      message.reply(Json.encode(asyncResult.result()));
    } else {
      message.fail(500, asyncResult.cause().getMessage());
    }
  });
});
```

Then you can call it:

```java
CatalogItem catalogItem = new CatalogItem();
vertx.eventBus().<String>request("dynamodb-example", Json.encode(catalogItem), asyncResult -> {
  if (asyncResult.succeeded()) {
    CatalogItem catalogItemResult = Json.decodeValue(asyncResult.result().body(), CatalogItem.class);
    // do something
  } else {
    // handle exception
  }
});
```

You can also work with JsonObject instead of strings, or define your own codecs to pass pojo's via the event-bus.

Comment: I am little new to vertx os can you please explain what do we mean by blocking the event bus. Is a blocking operation causes the above issue and it says waiting for more than 30 seconds which is also a very high number as my throughput was around 150 qps and dynamo call was taking 10 ms on average.

Comment: Also Can I simply wrap a completable future around my dynamo calls and make them async.What issue will be in that.

Comment: @saurabh blocking the event bus means doing things like `Thread.sleep(1000)` or executing any code the blocks the thread, which is a big no-no in vertx and non-blocking frameworks. It should not cause a timeout, this i assume happens because of some uncaught exception or something like that. You can wrap your code with a completable-future, the downside is you do not get the pros of working with vertx by delegating to another thread pool - but there is no problem with that.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you to use the library:
https://github.com/reactiverse/aws-sdk/tree/master/docs

This worked for me, and yes the correct way to use dynamo with vertx would be async.

Using maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.reactiverse</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Using Gradle:

```
implementation("io.reactiverse:aws-sdk:1.0.0")
```

How To:

```
DynamoDbAsyncClient dynamo = VertxSdkClient.withVertx(DynamoDbAsyncClient.builder().region(Region.EU_WEST_1), context).build();
```